# Java Spring Boot Self Join Getting Leading to Cycle

Tags: java, spring-boot

When i tried to self joining i got error "Direct self-reference leading to cycle" here is my entity code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    private User createdBy;
}
```

maybe its because it create this response

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "createdBy": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "createdBy": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "createdBy": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to limit it to maybe only 2 cycle and create response something like this?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "createdBy": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "createdBy": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: https://thorben-janssen.com/self-referencing-associations/

Answer (score 0):

DTO can help you handle this problem.

I think you need change your response in your controller from `User` to `UserDTO`.

```
public class UserDTO {
  int id;
  String name;
  int createBy;
//getter/setter
}
```

and mapper to convert `User` to `UserDTO`

```java
@Service
public class UserMapper implements Function<User, UserDto> {


    @Override
    public UserDto apply(User user) {
        return new UserDto(
                user.getId(),
                user.name(),
                user.getCreateBy().getId() 
        );
    }
}
```

If you need creator's info. You can get it by id again.

A faster way add `@JsonIgnore` on `createBy`, this field will be not convert to JSON

```
@JsonIgnore
private User createdBy;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, is it like this?
List<UserDTO> data = userRepository.findAll().stream().map(UserDTOMapper).collect(Collectors.toList());

that way isnt the createdBy would be int instead of the User object?

Comment: yes. you're correct